# htaccess: redirect certain file types to PHP script

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to prevent direct access to certain file types and redirect them to PHP script.

Example: user/browser requests

```
http://example.com/files/example.pdf
```

And I want it to be handled by download.php script. So basically final url should be

```
http://example.com/tools/download.php?file=files/example.pdf
```

What I've tried:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(psd|log|sh|pdf|doc)$">
RewriteRule ^/files/(.*)$   /tools/download.php?file=$1 [NC,L]
#Order Allow,Deny - with or without this
#Deny from all - with or without this
</FilesMatch>
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^.*\.(pdf|doc|xls|xlsx|docx|zip)$ /tools/download.php?file=$1 [R=301,L]
```

And I can't seem to get it work. Any ideas?

Comment: i think you are on wrong way...
you should place files folder out side of htdocs and handle it using php script. its beter way

Comment: I wish I could. This is pretty - lets say - customized project I support, and there are also links to files stored in docs in db (html content created by users). For now it seems to me easier to "intercept" it with htaccess rather than going throuh all the db.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend navigating all about index.php and then dealing with php code instead of htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*\.(pdf|doc|xls|xlsx|docx|zip)$ /tools/download.php?file=$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should do the trick. Also, deny all direct access and perform all routing via PHP.

Comment: Yes, should. But I've glitched myself a bit :) Clicking the link with test pdf file each time caused firefox to use some cached result and serve me this file. I had to force it to open in browser and press F5. Only then I saw redirect. But! Url shows "download.php?file=pdf" instead of full name. Probably this has to do something with "file=$1", I'll play with it.

Answer (score 0):

A better idea is to tell htaccess that if the file is there in the public folder, just serve it, and if not, fire it through your index.php, which would then no doubt route to your download controller.

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. The point is I cannot serve files directly because of a feature request: if content/article is disabled in cms, all the related files should not be available. Thatswhy I am thinking of disabling direct access and redirect file to download script (with parameter as a filename) which checks if file is enabled. I'll try to play with your solution (last 3 lines) to make it fit this and post on results.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I managed to make it work.

> **NB! RewriteRule keeps serving the file if it exists, it fires only if file
>   does not exist.**

The solution for me is to use RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch ^.*\.(psd|pdf|whatever)$ /tools/download.php?file=$0
```

...And play with it using Private browser windows on each link click, because browser - Firefox in my case - is somehow caching "click response".